# Is it safe to sync Oracle 19c to 12c via dblink?

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c, dblink

Source database: Oracle 19c
Target database: Oracle 12c, via dblink

Is it safe to sync tables from a higher version to a lower version?

1. I will create a materialized view on the target with scheduled refresh.
2. Then I will insert it to target tables.

Is this safe?

The reason for my question is that, when using datapump, based on my experience, when the source database is of a higher version than the target, I need to specify `[version=12.0.2.6]` in the `.par` files when exporting from Oracle 19c to 12c.

Comment: Yes, it is safe. The parameter for expdp is because of differences in the structured SQL that goes into the dump file, to ensure backwards compatibility with 12c. Using a DB link there is no issue because the 12c target is generating the SQL, which the 19c database will have no problem running.